# Laptop keyboard not working on MSI Bravo 15 B7E

Tags: keyboard, msi

Hardware: MSI Bravo 15 B7E laptop (https://us.msi.com/Laptop/Bravo-15-B7EX).  Bios has been updated to the most recent version (E158PAMS.102).

Issue: the keyboard on the laptop does not work past the grub screen.  On the grub screen, the up and down arrows work.  If I type “e” during grub, I can edit grub commands.  At the login screen, the laptop keyboard does not work.  I can plug in a USB keyboard, and the USB keyboard works.  After login the laptop keyboard does not work.  The laptop keyboard works in Windows.

Desired solution: get the laptop keyboard working in a current linux distribution.

The laptop keyboard works on Kubuntu 22.04.1 (from kubuntu-22.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso).  If Kubuntu 22.04.1 is installed and allowed to update the keyboard no longer works.  The keyboard backlight is lit,but nothing I do can make a key on the built-in keyboard respond.

Additional info added: The kernel that has a working laptop keyboard is: "Ubuntu, with Linux 5.15.0-43-generic", the kernel that is upgraded to where the laptop keyboard is "Ubuntu, with Linux 5.15.0-78-generic".

By going into the "Advanced options for Ubuntu", the "Ubuntu, with Linux 5.15.0-43-generic" kernel can be selected, and will consistently work.

Other “live” USB versions will boot, but the laptop keyboard does not work on them.  As an example Kubuntu 22.04.2 (from kubuntu-22.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso) will boot, but the keyboard does not work.

I have tried most solutions I can find online, none of them have solved the keyboard issue for me.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue,  did you get this working ?

Comment: same issue on MSI bravo 17. Seems to be MSI Bravo laptops issue. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1492421/msi-laptop-keyboard-not-working-on-ubuntu-22-04

Comment: Ubuntu 23.10 (and variants like Kubuntu 23.10) worked without issue, the keyboard and the wireless worked without issue.

I started with the beta release about 2 weeks before the 23.10 launch, and have had no issues with any of the updates since then.

Sorry I didn't think to update the post after getting the computer working.

Comment: Ubuntu 23.10 uses 6.5 kernel, I too switched to this kernel with 22.04, and the keyboard works but nVidia graphics card has issues. Were you able to use the nVidia card drivers with 23.10 and 6.5 kernel?

Comment: My laptop has Radeon graphics, and I have had no issues with it, but I also did an install of 23.10, not just matching the kernel number.