# MSI Laptop keyboard not working on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: kernel

My laptop (MSI Bravo 17) keyboard doesn't work with kernel 6.0.26 but works with 6.5.7. However, I need 6.0 because 6.5 is not supported by CUDA. Is there any way to fix this?

Possible solutions applied:

- updating drivers
- disabling slow keys

Comment: Those aren't standard kernels, which Ubuntu release are you running?  CUDA should not depend upon kernel (or video driver).  Get your system video running, then install CUDA from the .run script, rejecting any video driver offer and override the system bin/lib install locations to be the cuda/bin,lib. See 1219761 and 1077061 answers here.

Comment: That's the weird thing. My keyboard doesn't work on the default kernel and the officially updated kernel when I installed Ubuntu. And from the Nvidia documentation the support kernel for CUDA is 6.0.26. But my keyboard doesn't work in that kernel

Comment: having the exact same issue. Laptop Keyboard does not work even in live USB mode that is used for installing ubuntu. Using kernel 6.2.0-37-generic which is default kernel. External USB keyboard works. My laptop is MSI Bravo 17. Seems to be a general MSI Bravo Laptops issue https://askubuntu.com/questions/1482100/laptop-keyboard-not-working-on-msi-bravo-15-b7e

Comment: Yes MSI has horrible Linux support. But with WSL it fully works and u get fan control while running Linux

Comment: have a look if one of these can help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1422266/keyboard-not-working-on-lenovo-laptop/1495081#1495081

Comment: seen this answer, doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

From grub menu boot into kernel 6.0.26. in recovery mode, from root shell try:

```
apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-all
```

this will install required drivers for your keyboard.

Comment: I tried that normally and it didn't work. In recovery I can't use my keyboard in the menu

Comment: this advise does not work. Normally in grub menu, the laptop keyboard works. But when in recovery and logged into root, the laptop keyboard stopped working. Ran the above command from root using external usb keyboard, and it did nothing as it was already at latest drivers.