# Ensure that laptop does not get detected as tablet which disables keyboard (issue on MSI Bravo laptops)

Tags: kernel, 22.04, msi

I have an MSI Bravo 17 C7VFK laptop with AMD Ryzen 7 7735HS CPU and Nvidia 4060 graphics. Ubuntu does not detect its laptop keyboard at all. Even in the live USB used for installation, it does not detect the laptop keyboard. The keyboard works fine in the grub menu but not when booted into Ubuntu. The laptop keyboard works fine on the Windows side. I came across this [post](https://dev.to/krlz/review-msi-bravo-c7vf-1gfh) which describes the same issue that I am facing.

The issue seems to stem from the kernel (6.2.0-37-generic) that is being used with Ubuntu 22.04. This detects the laptop as a tablet device and completely disables the laptop keyboard. If I connect an external USB keyboard, it works fine, but not the laptop keyboard. Is there a way to make sure that the laptop is not detected as a tablet so that its keyboard does not get disabled?

The laptop's trackpad works fine. The issue is limited to laptop keyboard.

I am not alone in facing this issue. Others have faced the same issue. Am linking their posts here as well. My question is more directed toward the problem that is likely the root cause, hence posting as a separate question:

[MSI Laptop keyboard not working on Ubuntu 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1492421/msi-laptop-keyboard-not-working-on-ubuntu-22-04)

[Laptop keyboard not working on MSI Bravo 15 B7E](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1482100/laptop-keyboard-not-working-on-msi-bravo-15-b7e)

Comment: You probably have cause and effect reversed. It not that it "detects the laptop as a tablet device and completely disables the laptop keyboard". It's that the laptop keyboard is not detected, so it's considered a tablet device

Comment: With recent kernel updates, the problem went away. The keyboard gets detected fine.

Answer (score 0):

With recent kernel updates, the problem went away. The keyboard gets detected fine.
Current default kernel 6.5.0-17-generic in ubuntu 22.04 detects the keyboard fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with details as to which kernel version you updated to.