# Laptop recognised as a tablet

Tags: dual-boot, keyboard

I've installed Ubuntu as a dual boot with Windows 11, but my keyboard doesn't work. I found out that the laptop is recognized as a tablet device and hence the keyboard is disabled. I have a Lenovo Yoga Slim 7 Pro

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/q/1494859/1004020 . You have cause and effect reversed. Try updating the kernel